# Change image source using Javascript in a random order

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to write a script that randomly changes the image source of an element with one specified in the array. I have written the following but "target" returns undefined?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/20x20" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/20x20" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/20x20" /></li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let slideImages = [
   'http://www.placehold.it/100',
   'http://www.placehold.it/101',
   'http://www.placehold.it/103',
   'http://www.placehold.it/105',
   'http://www.placehold.it/99',
   'http://www.placehold.it/98',
   'http://www.placehold.it/96',
   'http://www.placehold.it/107'
]

let totalImages = slideImages.length;
let randomNo = Math.random() * totalImages;
let imageURL = Math.floor(randomNo)
let img = slideImages[imageURL];


let options = document.querySelectorAll('li');
let random = Math.random() * options.length;

let target = options[random];

var fadeImagesFn = (target, img) => {
   console.log(img, target);
}

    fadeImagesFn(img);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in those two lines:

```
let random = Math.random() * options.length;
let target = options[random];
```

`Math.random()` returns a floating-point value between 0 and 1. Multiplied by `length` of `options`, you'll get numbers between 0 and `options.length`, but not necessarily integers.

For example, if `Math.random` returns 0.5, and there are 7 options, `random` will contain a value of `3.5`.

Subsequently, indexing `options` with a non-integral number will simply return `undefined`. You need to make those values integral again, e.g. by using `Math.floor`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a float index of an array, which of course is undefined. Use `Math.floor` before indexing.

```js
let options = document.querySelectorAll('li');
let random = Math.random() * options.length; // <- float
let target = options[random]; // <- array-like [ float ] = undefined
```

Comment: Okay, yeah, you know what I mean, the probability of `Math.random()*options.length` being an integer is absurdly small 